# Scoail engine url always holding index.php

Tags: .htaccess, socialengine

In my social engine web site , it always shows mydomain.com/index.php instead of mydomain.com

For example when we access the member page it shows mydomain.com/index.php/member , but actually I would like to get it as mydomain.com/members

Please see my htacess code under /public folder  here

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(avi|flv|mov|wmv|wma|mp3|mp4|m4a|mkv|swf|pdf|doc|ppt|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A29030400
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_expires.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Expires "Sun, 1 Jan 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
        Header append Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public"
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I solve this ?

Thanks in advance
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Why your .htaccess is inside /public folder? It should be inside a root socialengine folder, where .htaccess enables rewrite mode...